# How To Convert Datetime Sharepoint Get Response to Text

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint

I get Sharepoint datetime column using angularjs http methods, and the result is  "/Date(1554798600000)/". How to convert that to Datetime format (DDMMYYYY) ?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to map the values through some sort of string manipulation

```
var strippedValue = "/Date(1554798600000)/".replace(/\/Date\(|\)\//g, '');

var actualDate = new Date(Number(strippedValue));
```

With the `actualDate` javascript date object, you can either use an angular filter or javascript date methods like `getDate()`, `getMonth()`, `getYear()` to reformat the date however you want it

Comment: Thanks for inspiring me Katherine

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All, I tried use this code in angularjs

```
 var convert = StartTime.replace(/\/Date\(|\)\//g,'');

 var newDate = new Date(Number(convert)).toString();
```

And works.